# download large file from Jetty (ambari webhdfs) is slow

Tags: jetty, ambari, webhdfs

I have a file about 5G, download from hdfs using python client at 12M/s, buy my network could reach 500M/s, and smaller file work fine. Then I reproduced this problem with curl.

Here is curl debug log:

curl -v -X GET http://x.x.x.x/file

```
> GET /webhdfs/v1/user/sohuvideo/online/srcFile/188/718/188718791/dat1_188718791_2020_4_11_17_4_172647e6e60.mp4?op=OPEN&user.name=sohuvideo&namenoderpcaddress=sotocyon&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: x.x.x.com:50075
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:01:26 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:01:26 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:01:26 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:01:26 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
< 
{ [data not shown]
100  119M    0  119M    0     0  13.0M      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:-- 12.1M^C
```

After some digging, I found if attach header **Connection: close** to the request, it could end up much faster.

curl -v -H "Connection: close" -X  GET http://x.x.x.x/file

```
> GET /webhdfs/v1/user/sohuvideo/online/srcFile/188/718/188718791/dat1_188718791_2020_4_11_17_4_172647e6e60.mp4?op=OPEN&user.name=sohuvideo&namenoderpcaddress=sotocyon&offset=0 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: x.x.x.com:50075
> Accept: */*
> Connection: close
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Expires: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:00:13 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:00:13 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:00:13 GMT
< Date: Tue, 21 Apr 2020 03:00:13 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Connection: close
< Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
< 
{ [data not shown]
100 4517M    0 4517M    0     0   138M      0 --:--:--  0:00:32 --:--:--  153M
* Closing connection 0
```

I think this probably caused by **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** from server when file is large, server chose this because when server transfer the file the file size has not yet be decided, chunked stream could give a lots of overhead. If given **Connection: close** then server would not use **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** to indicate the end of steam, just close the connection instead.

Is there any way to fix this from server side?

Comment: Jetty 6.1.26 was declared End of Life back in Nov 2010.  Consider upgrading.  [See Jetty Versions Table](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html)

Comment: Sadly, I have no direct control over the server,  they are reluctant to upgrade.

Comment: Tested on Jetty 9.4.28.v20200408, we got it up to 13TB (we got bored and stopped there) with no difference in speed between chunked and non-chunked, easily saturating the 1-gigabit network we are on.  Perhaps the problem is on your client?

Comment: Also, why does your curl output show `Expires`, `Date`, and `Pragma` response headers multiple times?

Comment: Be aware of the security issues with Jetty 6.x -> https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/security-reports.html

Comment: Thanks for the input,  this python client just use python lib **requests** to download file, and I tested **requests** for chunked download, it worked fine. I guess it's this particular Jetty(6.1.26) version which is broken.

Comment: Had no idea why `Expires`, `Date`, and `Pragma` repeated. When test curl on my simple chunked server nothing like this appeared.